# Why is a Linux host interpretting the zero key as enter?

Tags: linux, debian, putty, keyboard, stty

I am connecting to a Debian virtual machine using PuTTY, and every time I press the 0 (zero) key, the command line behaves as if I've pressed enter.  Why might this be and how can I change it?

Perhaps also relevant: I'm connecting from Windows 10, using PuTTYtray, and have installed a custom keymap created using Microsoft Keyboard Layout Generator 1.4 (which leaves 0 alone but changes its shifted behaviour).  The Debian machine is a DigitalOcean droplet.  I've been using it for about a year and have never noticed anything like this.

Things I've tried:

- Pressing 0 in other applications -- normal behaviour
- Pressing 0 in other PuTTY sessions on other hosts -- normal behaviour
- Trying another shell (bash instead of zsh) -- 0 still acts as enter
- Disconnecting and reconnecting -- same behaviour
- Keypad 0 -- also acts as enter
- Shift and 0 -- works as expected (> on my keyboard)
- Connecting to the problem host via another (Ubuntu) host -- 0 acts normally
- Connecting to another host via the problem host -- even weirder! -- 0 acts as if I had pressed 0 THEN enter
- GNU screen -- 0 still acts as enter

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please review your keyboard settings and advise if you're using a nonstandard config.  http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.58/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-keyboard

Comment: This just happened to me again, 3 years later, the next time I spun up a new DO droplet.  Weird!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like maybe somehow you got

```
stty eol 0
```

into one of your profile scripts somehow.  Try

```
stty sane
```

and see if that fixes it.

Comment: On second thought... setting eol to 0 (or any other character) isn't causing this behavior in putty for me, which is strange because `stty erase 0` does set 0 to backspace.

Comment: `stty sane` stops the crazy behaviour, but neither `ssty eol 0` nor `stty erase 0` then have any noticeable effect.  Thanks for fixing my problem, but I still wonder exactly what caused it.